# How to name a thread?

Tags: kotlin

How can I name this `Thread`?

```
    override val t: Thread = Thread {
        try {
            transmit()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Transmitter throws exception: $e")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thread has a setName method, you might want to try that one

Comment: @aldok how can I access the thread from within this code? so that I can call setname?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a named thread using the `thread` function from [stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html):

```
fun thread(
    start: Boolean = true, 
    isDaemon: Boolean = false, 
    contextClassLoader: ClassLoader? = null, 
    name: String? = null, 
    priority: Int = -1, 
    block: () -> Unit
): Thread
```

Just change your code:

```
override val t: Thread = thread(name = "transmitter thread") {
        try {
            transmit()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Transmitter throws exception: $e")
        }
    }
```

In order to set the thread's name from within the thread, you can't use `Thread`'s constructor that receives `Runnable`. You need to subclass the `Thread` class using the object expression:

```
val thread = object : Thread() {
  override fun run() {
       name = "thread with random name: ${Math.random()}"
  }
}
```

Comment: `you can't use Thread's constructor that receives Runnable` Why is it?

Comment: Since the lambda represent the `Runnable` instance and not the `Thread` instance. Therefore, you can't set the thread's name inside it because from the language point of view, there is no thread but `Runnable`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, I like the acepted (other answer) for my code it is the easiest.. however my code's a bit of a mes now so I can't run it to test if it worked - are you guys saying it won't work?

Comment: The other answer uses another constructor of both `Runnable` and name `String` so it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Thread's constructor, although due to how its arguments are ordered, you'll have to do this:

```
override val t: Thread = Thread({
    try {
        transmit()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Transmitter throws exception: $e")
    }}, "Your name here")
}
```